# shell: how to make garbled from spanish in a txt file to be shown normally

Tags: shell, encoding

i am read a txt file with some spanish characters into Postgresql, but found error message "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0Xdc, 0x45,

i used the following code to get the encoding for the file,

```
file -bi CAT_CELDAS_20190626.txt
```

the result is:

```
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1,
```

Then i use iconv to convert the encoding from iso-8859-1 to utf-8,

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 CAT_CELDAS_20190626.txt -o CAT_CELDAS_20190626_new.txt
```

after conversion, i check the encoding of the new file, it is utf-8, but the garbled is still there,

```
503|706010004403418|3418|3418|13.959919|-89.1149|275|1900|GSM|3418|Hacienda Asunci髇|1|CUSCATLAN|SUCHITOTO|706|1|44|3418|470||
503|706010004403417|3417|3417|13.959919|-89.1149|30|1900|GSM|3417|Hacienda Asunci髇|1|CUSCATLAN|SUCHITOTO|706|1|44|3417|470||
```

Comment: for the txt file, after i open in notepad++, and after i change charset to "iso-8859-1", the garbled is back to normal, but don't know how to do it in Linux,

Comment: I would proceed as follows: First look at the original file on hexadecimal level (for instance, using `od -cx FILENAME`) and verify manually, that the characters in question indeed are valid under iso-8859-1. Then do the same with the converted file and check manually for validity under UTF-8. Also verify whether the file starts with a BOM, and whether the BOM is correct.

Comment: In your case, the offending part is obviously the `ón` in Asunción. In the input, this should be (hex) D36E. In UTF8, the ó should become C3B3 and the n should stay 6E of course. I don't see how `iconv` could possibly produce a DC45, since you did not use the `-s` option.